# Token not provided en autenticacion con JWT Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

Tengo ese error en laravel ya que cuando hago la solicitud envio los datos del usuario y me genera el token pero trato de agregar esto y me dice token not provided

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser();
```

Este es el codigo de mi controlador

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Utils\Enums\EnumResponse;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
   {
       // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
       // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
       // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);

   }

     public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {   

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'success',
            'result' => [
                'token' => $token,
            ],
        ]);


        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    }
```

De esta manera funciona pero si le agrego este codigo no funciona me da el error

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Utils\Enums\EnumResponse;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
   {
       // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
       // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
       // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);

   }

     public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {   

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }

         $user = JWTAuth::toUser();

        if( $user ) {

            $data = [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'profile_photo' => $user->profile_photo,
                'birth_date' => $user->birth_date,
                'biography' => $user->biography,
                'country_id' => $user->country_id,
                'state_id' => $user->state_id,
                'sex' => $user->sex,
                'phone' => $user->phone,
                'city_id' => $user->city_id,
                'weight' => $user->weight,
                'size' => $user->size,
                'username' => $user->username,
                'ranking' => $user->ranking,
                'user_type' => $user->user_type,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'token' => $request->token
            ];
        return responseRequest( EnumResponse::SUCCESS, $data );
    }
```

Ayuda por favor no se como usar `$user = JWTAuth::toUser();` para pasarle el token incluso si se lo paso así `$user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);`   No funciona

Answer (score -2):

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()
```

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, pero por favor revisa [answer] y trata de mejorar tu respuesta, el solo colocar código sin ninguna explicación se consider de baja calidad